# How to get the value inside an "object" - Javascript - Google map API

Tags: javascript

this is a simple question. In PHP, when you want to know what's inside an array, you say :

```
print_r ($array);
```

But how do you do it in Javascript?? When I try to print the value of "overlay", I get "object Object"...

```
listener_rightclick = GEvent.addListener(map, 'singlerightclick', function(point, src, overlay){
    if (overlay){
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'cliqué ! ' + overlay;
        GEvent.removeListener(listener_rightclick);
        map.removeOverlay(overlay);
        ecouter_clicks_pts();
    }
    //document.getElementById('pt_latlng').innerHTML = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx: '+overlay;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks guys! But what I was looking for was this :

option #1 : toSource() function

```
document.getElementById('info_div').innerHTML = GMarker.toSource();
```

Option #2 : for ... in function

```
var info;
for (x in GMarker){info = info + '   ' + x}
document.getElementById('info_div').innerHTML = info;
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is only for debugging purposes, I'd use Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

To print the array contents to the debugging console, all you have to do is:

```
console.log(overlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    name:'john'
}

function inspect( obj ) {
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            console.log( prop + ':' + obj[prop] );
        }
    }
}

inspect( obj )
```

Assuming you have Firebug installed, this is one way to inspect an object.

Comment: Firebug has a built-in object inspector already. Why would you need to loop over properties manually?